# Finding second partial derivatives with arctan

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have a question saying Find all second partial derivatives of $z=arctan(\frac{x+y}{1-xy})$. For the first derivative with respect to x I used u substitution and wound up with $$ \frac{1}{1+u^2}*\frac{1+y^2}{(1-xy)^2}$$ Putting back in the value for u, I was left with what was a nightmare to simplify and wasn't able to do anything with it. The answer for Zxx is supossed to be $\frac{-2x}{(1+x^2)^2}$

Comment: We have $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\arctan x = \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$. Using this, by the Chain Rule, we have $\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{y (x+y)}{(1-x y)^2}+\dfrac{1}{1-x y}\right)}{1+\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)^2} $. Now simplify and arrive at: $\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$. The next partial of that is straightforward. You can use the product instead of the quotient rule rule since you can write the ugliness of the arctan argument as $(x+y)(1 - x y)^{-1}$ and that makes life much easier! Try it this way and see if it easier.

Comment: My My biggest problem I guess is just trying to simplify it all. I always seem to make some mistake somewhere that leaves me with the wrong thing.

Comment: What did you set $u=$ to?

Comment: @GFauxPas I set it to x+y / 1-xy